# \no inside a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel-french

`\no` inside the node is printed as 'no' rather than the associated symbol. How to get the symbol, instead?

```
\documentclass
    %[letterpaper]
{minimal}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{25}{30}}
%\newcommand\HUGE{\fontsize{50}{60} \selectfont}
%\newcommand\HUGE{\fontsize{180}{60} \selectfont}
\makeatother


%\shortdate
\ddmmyydate

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox
{
  \tikz[color=red,opacity=0.5]
  \node{
    Exemplaire \no 1
  };
}

\newwatermark*[
%allpages,
pages={1-},
color=red!50,angle=90,scale=2,xpos=-95,ypos=0
]
{
  \usebox\mybox
}


\begin{document}

\usebox\mybox

Exemplaire \no 1

%ultimate use:
%\includepdf[pages={1-}]{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweexample−image−a.pdf}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The problem is not in `TikZ` but into the savedbox. If you include `\tikz \node{exemplaire \no 1};` in your text, the result is correct.

Comment: The ultimate use is save box inside a watermark, as shown  in comment.

Comment: More accurately  the macro and settings of babel (here those of french.ldf) are loaded only  at`\begin{document}`. Hence they are not yet available inside the preamble. The savebox,  if defined after `\begin{document}` should work too.